# Error sorting list using Collections.sort

Tags: java, list, collections

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when i try to sort a list with by doing the Collections.sort(list2)

the list contains the following strings

> [BOOTH 4, ENP ROOM, BOOTH 6, C&T
>   Waiting Area, C&T Waiting Area, C&T
>   Waiting Area, BOOTH 10, BOOTH 7, BOOTH
>   3, BOOTH 1, C&T Waiting Area, C&T
>   Waiting Area, C&T Waiting Area, C&T
>   Waiting Area, BOOTH 1, C&T Waiting
>   Area, C&T Waiting Area, C&T Waiting
>   Area, C&T Waiting Area, C&T Waiting
>   Area, C&T Waiting Area, C&T Waiting
>   Area, C&T Waiting Area, C&T Waiting
>   Area, BOOTH 10, C&T Waiting Area, C&T
>   Waiting Area, C&T Waiting Area, C&T
>   Waiting Area, C&T Waiting Area, C&T
>   Waiting Area, C&T Waiting Area, null,
>   null, null, null, null, null, null,
>   null, null, null, null, null, null,
>   null, null, null, null]

Do i need to use comparator for this list?

Comment: "I'm getting an exception" is not a useful error report. Stack traces are there for a reason.

Comment: @user521180 which exception?some stack trace or code would actually help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `null` values before sorting. They can't be sorted

Comment: Strictly, they *can* be sorted, but only if you provide a Comparator object that does something sensible with `null` references.

Comment: @Stephen C - Yes, you are right. Couldn't see any comparators in the invocation: Collections.sort(list2)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a comparator that can handle null values.  E.g.

```
private static final class NullsFirstComparator implements Comparator<String> {
  public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
    if (lhs == rhs)
      return 0;
    if (lhs == null)
      return -1;
    if (rhs == null)
      return 1;
    return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
  }
}
```

Which will sort the null values first (they are less than everything)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `NullComparator` in Apache commons. [It](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/comparators/package-summary.html) provide lot of useful utilities for writing comparator